# NominatimPOIProvider: request failed. (osmdroid bonuspack)

Tags: android, osmdroid, nominatim

I tried using the NominatimPOIProvider as described in the Tutorial_2 on http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2 using that code:

```
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.501397,9.620427);
    NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider();
    ArrayList<POI> pois = poiProvider.getPOICloseTo(startPoint, "cinema", 50, 0.1);
```

But I constantly get the error `NominatimPOIProvider: request failed.`. Does anybody know how to fix or avoid that? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it is because newer SDK do not allow network communication in the main thread - as it is mentioned in the first chapter of the tutorial itself. So to run through the tutorial, you need to set the sdk version to something below Honeycomb, e.g.

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, solved it by using the MapQuestRoadManager, instead of OSRMRoadManager

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1#2-playing-with-the-roadmanager